# Windows 7, Locking & unlocking historic data log

Tags: windows-7

how can i find the historic or past data of event id 4800 and 4801. I need to know when did i log in and log off from my PC last month. How can i search last months data? Please help. Your assistance will be greatly appreciated in this.

Comment: Have you checked the event viewer? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the Event Viewer, open the Security Log, and use the "*Filter Current Log...*" option to filter by event ID and time/date.

[image: Event Viewer Filter]

Comment: thank you for your swift assistant, i tried doing the above but it is not pulling out any data for last month. Is there any other way to retrieve last month data.

Comment: Not if it's been deleted.  How far back does your Security Event Log go?  Does it have _any_ entries in it from last month?  In the end, that's the Event log, if they're not in there then there's nothing to look at. :)

Comment: It is showing only today's data. I guess its overwriting the previous logs. Thanks techie007 :) i guess i would need to change the setting of log. many thanks for your help & assistant.

Comment: No problem, feel free to throw me an upvote. ;)